# Laravel Socialite - Google Provider

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with Laravel 8 Socialite for Google. I don't know how I can get user birthday information from Google provider. Google give me a lot of information but  dont't give me age/date of birth column

My Code
https://pasteboard.co/JyuRdSm.png
https://pasteboard.co/JyuRHVf.png

Comment: instead of uploading image of your code provide code snippet here , i suggest to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & know about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the appropriate scope that returns that piece of information:

From https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes, it seems to be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read`.